# Verificar existência de função em C#

Tags: c#, reflexão

Como posso verificar se uma função existe em `C#`? Creio que tenho que usar algum tipo de reflexão, mas não conheço muito sobre isso. Há alguma maneira de obter a lista de argumentos da função, caso ela exista?

Por exemplo:

```
public class ClasseA {

public bool Funcao1(string a, string b){       

    //Código da função
}

public bool Funcao2(string a, string b){
    //Código da função
}

public bool Funcao10(string a, string b) {
   //Código da função
}

public bool VerificaExistenciaFuncoes(){
{
       bool bTodasExistem = true;
       for(int i = 1; i<=10;i++){

         // Aqui quero fazer algo do tipo:
         // Se função não existe "Funcao" + i -> bTodasExistem = false;
      }              

    return bTodasExistem;

}

}
```

Comment: Verificar onde? Pra que?

Comment: Vou alterar a pergunta para que fique mais específica

Comment: Pra que fazer isto? Todas existem, está pronto ali, esse uso não faz sentido. C# não é uma linguagem dinâmica que a função pode ou não existir. Precisaria mostrar um caso onde isso é útil, nesse caso a `VerificaExistenciaFuncoes()` não faz nada que já não seja de conhecimento do programador.

Comment: Então agora precisa dar mais informações do que quer de fato pra gente ver o que fazer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Eu não vejo um sentido em fazer isso. Como foi dito nos comentários, [C# não é uma linguagem dinâmica que a função pode ou não existir.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194724/verificar-exist%C3%AAncia-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-c/194736#comment401413_194724) Todavia, irei responder assim mesmo.

Como você disse na pergunta, você pode utilizar `Reflection` para verificar se o método existe ou não no objeto. Um exemplo simples seria isso:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var classeA = new ClasseA();
        var existeFuncoes = VerificaExistenciaFuncoes(classeA, "Funcao");
        Console.WriteLine(existeFuncoes);

    }
    public static bool VerificaExistenciaFuncoes(object obj, string prefixMethod)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        bool bTodasExistem = true;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var function = type.GetMethod(prefixMethod + i);
            //estou percorrendo o laço todo, mas poderia retornar false de uma vez
            if (function == null)
                bTodasExistem = false;
        }

        return bTodasExistem;
    }
}


public class ClasseA
{

    public bool Funcao1(string a, string b)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool Funcao2(string a, string b)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool Funcao10(string a, string b)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note que separei o método `VerificaExistenciaFuncoes()` da `classeA` e coloquei 2 parâmetros para ele, `obj` e `prefixmethod`.

Obj nada mais é do que o objeto que você está verificando se o método existe ou não.

prefixMethod é o prefixo da função que deseja verificar. Como o que irá mudar em seu exemplo é somente o número, eu coloquei esse parâmetro para ficar mais fácil explicar.

Agora, para verificar se o método existe ou não, basta utilizar o [Type.GetMethod()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.type.getmethod(v=vs.110).aspx), passando o nome do método que deseja verificar.

[Veja funcionando no DotNetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JzeRb3)

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo de como pegar os métodos e sua lista de parâmetros:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Teste
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Teste t = new Teste();
            //Pega todas as informações dos metodos a partir do tipo do objeto (classe), você pode informar através das flags um filtro (publico, privado)
            MethodInfo[] methodInfos = Type.GetType(t.GetType().ToString()) 
                           .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (MethodInfo method in methodInfos)
            {
                //Mostra o nome do metodo
                System.Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
                //Pega todos os parametros do metodo
                foreach(ParameterInfo parameter in method.GetParameters())
                {
                    //Posição do parametro
                    int pos = parameter.Position;
                    //Nome do tipo do parametro (int, string)
                    string nameOfType = parameter.ParameterType.Name;
                    //Nome do parametro
                    string nameOfParam = parameter.Name;
                    System.Console.WriteLine(pos);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(nameOfType);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(nameOfParam);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Teste
    {
        public void meuMetodo(string arg1, string arg2)
        {

        }

        public int meuMetodo2(int arg1, int arg2)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Referências:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.parametertype(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.reflection.methodinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Existe, e já está respondido em Inglês aqui 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499593/c-sharp-how-to-check-if-namespace-class-or-method-exists-in-c

Resposta mais precisa em Inglês e traduzida:

> You can resolve a Type from a string by using the Type.GetType(String) >method. For example:
>
> Para resolver uma class a partir de uma String pode-se utilizar a função Type.GetType(String)

`Type myType = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass");`

> You can then use this Type instance to check if a method exists on the >type by calling the GetMethod(String) method. For example:
>
> A partir da classe, é possível validar a existência de uma função através da função GetMethod(String). Por Exemplo:

`MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("MyMethod");`

> Both GetType and GetMethod return null if no type or method was found for the given name, so you can check if your type/method exist by checking if your method call returned null or not.
>
> Tanto a função GetType e GetMethod, retornarão null caso para a String fornecida, não exista a classe ou a função respectivamente.
>
> Finally, you can instantiate your type using >Activator.CreateInstance(Type) For example:
>
> Por fim, a partir dos dados obtidos, é possível instanciar um objecto da classe a partir do função Activator.CreateInstance(Type)

`object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);`

Relativamente a segunda parte da pergunta, para obter os parametros, existe a função GetParameters() que pertence a class MethodInfo.:

`ParameterInfo[] pars = myMethod.GetParameters();
 foreach (ParameterInfo p in pars) {
            Console.WriteLine(p.ParameterType);
 }`